Emacs how Company tooltip bind tab key?
Juste wonder how to bind the tab key when displaying data from the company tooltip selection window to select the underlying value.  I use company anf lsp backend.
(with-eval-after-load 'company
  (lambda() (set-local-key (kbd "<tab>") 'company-complete-selection)))

I guest that is not 'company-complete-selection to use while the popup window is displayed.  The only key working is the "return" key to select from the dropdown list.
